# Problems with webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, floating-action-button

I'm creating an application that displays a webview and has a button that opens the Android settings. My problem is that when I add this button, the webview stops working and only show a white screen that doesn't charge. What am I doing wrong? I leave the code below:

PD: If I delete the code starting from "//init code" it works....

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.becas.apn_mexico

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.view.View
import com.becas.apn_mexico.base.BaseActivity
import com.becas.apn_mexico.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton


class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding>() {

    companion object {
        private const val URL_LINK_WEBSITE = "https://apn.tutorialez.net/index.php/landing-page/"
    }

    override fun setupViewBinding(): ActivityMainBinding {
        return ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun setupViewModel() {
    }

    override fun setupUI(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding.mainWebview.loadUrlExt(URL_LINK_WEBSITE)
        showAdBanner(binding.adsView.adsPhoneTabSpecialSmartBanner)
        showAdInterstitial(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial))
    }

    // Init Code
    private lateinit var fab: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fab = findViewById(R.id.abrir_configuracion)

        // Configurando el setonclicklistener

        fab.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(i) })
    }
    
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.becas.apn_mexico.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ads_view" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/abrir_configuracion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/ads_view"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentDescription="@string/open_config_apn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/ads_view"
        layout="@layout/ads_phone_tab_special_smart_banner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not using the viewbinding to inflate your view:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // You need to get here the binding and put it into the ContentView method
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    fab = findViewById(R.id.abrir_configuracion)
    
    // Configurando el setonclicklistener
    
    fab.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
        val i = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS)
        startActivity(i) })
}
```

Alternatively, the problem is in your layout. Can you remove the

```xml
<include
    android:id="@+id/ads_view"
    layout="@layout/ads_phone_tab_special_smart_banner" />
```

From your layout and let me know if you get the expected result?